# What is a term for a form that has been filled out?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, technology

Assuming the definition of 'form' as follows (see definition #6 [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aform&oq=define%3Aform&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i59.3583j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8)):

"a printed document with blank spaces for information to be inserted."

What could you call a printed document with the blank spaces filled in, if you were trying to use a word that differentiated those printed documents from the ones that haven't been filled in?

**UPDATE**

To help clarify the situation a little more, let me explain the two concepts that we are working with.  We have several online 'forms' that people fill out in order to provide us with background information about them.  We also keep hard-copies of the information they have provided, but these 'forms' do not correlate directly with the online 'forms.'  For example, online we have "Personal Information", "Biographical", and "Financial" forms.  The printed 'forms' contain information from several of these 'online' forms.

For example, the financial form pulls name, address, etc., from the personal information form.  So you see, the printed forms are not really submissions because they are created after the 'submissions' have been gathered.  They are also not really the 'completed' or 'filled' forms.  Also, 'printed' won't work either because, although I mentioned we keep hard copies, they are also used electronically as well.  We are looking for very unambiguous terms because of the confusion that has resulted in the past (you would be surprised).

Comment: What about: "client data/facts/details" for those *forms* that are not visible to the public online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not to be filled in and has been printed, it is as you say, a hard copy. The form is to be filled. The report is what's printed.

If the result is to be stored and no longer edited, the Data Form Summarization or Aggregation Report contains the documentation collected from the various forms. In short, it's a *report*. That's the term database applications use to present the difference between data in (form) and data out.

Answer (score 8):

I would call it a **completed form**.

Comment: I was hoping for a single word, but perhaps this is the best I'm going to get.

Comment: you could call the submitted, completed form a "submission".

Comment: The completed form becomes a submission when you turn it in.

Answer (score 2):

At the point that the form has been completed, it's safe to refer to it by it's taxonomic designation as in

- A *completed registration form* can now simply be referred to as *a Registration*
- A *completed ballot sheet* can now simply be referred to as *a vote/ballot*

etc

Comment: _ballot_ doesn't distinguish whether it's completed or not. "Pick up a ballot at the polling station and fill it in."

Comment: @Barmar - depends on the timeframe/context of reference. *count the ballots at the end of the polls*

Comment: The point is that the word itself doesn't specify whether it's filled in, just the context. You can count the ballots at the beginning, too (to make sure you have enough for all the voters).

Answer (score 2):

I would go with **consolidated** forms.  Complete the rest of the consolidated form and return it to the desk.

But your process sounds very confusing so I would not expect a miracle by changing the form name.

Answer (score 1):

As your example is unique to your company there is nothing to stop you inventing your own word, as long as everyone involved understands what it means.

This could be an acronym, eg **PIB** (personal info, biographical) or **DEC** (data entry complete).

You could call them **cooked** (in the sense of "What's cooking?" = "What's happening?" *Cooked* here meaning *done*.)

Or you could simply pick a word at random to refer to them. Your web address is paxcopia - call them **paxed**.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply call them "[hand-filled forms](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/O/OMR.html)."

> [Printed and hand-filled forms will not be accepted](http://www.ifla.org/membership/administration/member-details-form).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the one word you are looking for is "pre-populated."

In other words, if you are filling out a form and the date section, for instance, is pre-populated with MM/DD/YYYY, you know the owner of the form wants the date to be filled out with an American date format. Or in some instances, the form might be pre-populated with the entire form pre-filled out with a generic name and address such as:

Name: Mrs. Happy Customer

Street Address: 123 Main Street

City, State, Zip: Happyville, Anywhere 99999

Website: http:// www.yourwebsite . com

Twitter: @

Hope the word "pre-populated" is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi @user262713. Welcome to ELL SE! It helps if you can provide external references for your answer. For example, you could link to a definition of pre-populate.